# Antd responsive Header cause overflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using  and  to make a header. When the screen is not very small, the responsiveness looks good.
[image]

But if the screen become smaller, the dropdown will be overflowed. The "NavItem 2" and "NavItem 3" is not displayed properly.

[image]

However, if I keep reducing the width, it will back to normal again.

[image]

Anyone know how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Assign a class to popup using `overflowedIndicatorPopupClassName` prop and then use these styles `left: 50% !important; transform: translateX(-50%) !important; min-width: 95vw !important;`. This may solve your overflow issue